# How can i get the configured Emails in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to get the user emails those are configured in iPhone using cocoa touch. How can i do that .

Thank you for answers .

Comment: What "user emails"?  Do you mean the ones the user has stored in the address book?  The e-mail address of the user himself?  What?

Answer (score 2):

This code will fetch all contacts in the address book and output the email addresses associated with them:

```
// get a list of all contacts in the address book db
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef contacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(ab);

for( int i = 0; i < nPeople; ++i ) {
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(contacts,i);

    // output the contact's name
    CFStringRef firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    CFStringRef lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSString *contactFirstLast = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@:",
                                    firstName, lastName];
    NSLog(@"%@", contactFirstLast);

    // output all email addresses stored for the contact
    ABMultiValueRef emailRef = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    CFIndex nEmails = ABMultiValueGetCount(emailRef);
    CFArrayRef emails = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailRef);
    for( int j = 0; j < nEmails; ++j ) {
        CFStringRef email = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(emails, j);
        NSLog(@"\t%@", email);
    };

    // clean up
    CFRelease(emailRef);
    CFRelease(firstName);
    CFRelease(lastName);
}

CFRelease(contacts);
```